# How can I retrieve image in listtile use firebase storage

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to retrieve image in listtile but I got an error

> The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

and I try to use then and setstate after get value but it got an infinite loop - how can I change it ?

Here is my method

```
Future<String> getImageUrl(String image) async {
    final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('images/$image');
    String url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
    print('url ====> $url');
    return url;
}
```

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: animals,
            builder: (
              BuildContext context,
              AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot,
            ) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('Something Went Wrong!');
              }
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Text('Loading');
              }

              final data = snapshot.requireData;

              return Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 65),
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: data.size,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final url = getImageUrl(data.docs[index]['picture0']);
                    return ListTile(
                       leading: CircleAvatar(
                         radius: 30,
                         backgroundImage:
                             NetworkImage(url),
                       ),
                      title: Text(
                        '${data.docs[index]['animalName']}',
                      ),
                      subtitle: Text(
                        '${data.docs[index]['animalDetail']}',
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
```

my picture data is

> picture0 ====> scaled_1d2be9d3-fe7b-4ddb-aea6-b5e2f4b87d568770068469124029055.jpg

url give me is

> url ====> https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/clone-sql.appspot.com/o/images%2Fscaled_1d2be9d3-fe7b-4ddb-aea6-b5e2f4b87d568770068469124029055.jpg?alt=media&token=1832079e-1fda-4c74-b3be-2ceb5e9dfc9f

Answer (score 0):

you can use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) to create the UI of the image.